# Array de distintas propiedades con el mismo id en un objeto - React JS

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Estoy recorriendo un objeto que tiene un array de objetos dentro de una propiedad y debo acceder al id de un objeto para verificar cuales colores de mis objetos tienen el mismo id y hacer un array de los distintos colores del mismo id para desplegarlo en el frontend como un concatenado. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Aqui les dejo la imagen del objeto sobre el cual estoy sacando las ids y colores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los dm_id son los que necesito para poder hacer el array de color_bom_header con el mismo dm_id

Aquí está el codigo que hace que esto suceda pero no funciona bien :(

```
this.state.stylesArray = this.props.location.state.stylesCombo.components.map((index, current) => {
        const col = this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = index.color_bom_name)
        if(this.state.stylesCombo.components && this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].dm_id === index.dm_id){
          if(this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].dm_name === index.dm_name){
            this.state.colorStArray.push(col)
            this.state.cstarr = [...new Set(this.state.colorStArray)]
          }
        }else{
          this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = current.color_bom_name)
        }
        this.state.stylesCombo.components && (this.state.stylesCombo.components[current].style_colors = this.state.cstarr)   
      })
```

Comment: en el `map` tienes al revés el `index` y el `current`. Aunque veo que de todos modos utilizaste `current` como `index` y viceversa así que ese no es el problema

Comment: Es posible que en la segunda linea hayas puesto `=` en vez de `===`?